# How to I point to a local copy of Python on a Linux Server?

Tags: python, linux, server, installation

I have downloaded and compiled Python 2.7.12 into my $HOME directory on a Linux server.

Presently, I am having trouble setting that version of python into my local path and to be the default version even though I have now added a reference in my .bash_profile. See attached.

When I

```
 which python
```

I see that I am directed to the default 2.6 installation in /usr/bin/python.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Do you need more information?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`, you're adding `$HOME/bin` to the *end* of your `PATH` variable (so it's the *last* place that is checked). If you want this python to be the priority, you need to add it to the *beginning* of your `PATH`:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Hello and thank you so much! I have now updated to -PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.12/:$PATH
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.12:$PATH

export PATH
export PYTHONPATH    - But the default is still the other installation after a refresh of the .bash_profile and logging out and back in.

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out. A little path problem, but, with your help, the .bash_profile statements are now correct. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!